# Images is not shown in my Full screen Activity from my json response..? while swiping also

Tags: java, android, json, url

**How to swipe my full screen images from gridview...and that images should Loading from JSON response...?**

i'm new to android...please help me friends...

But i want to use only **One url** in my program(**JSON URL**)...from that i need
**Gridview--->FullScreenImage(zooming and swiping)**

This is my gridView Activity...

```
package com.example.admin.loadingimagefromwebgridandswipe;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.admin.adapter.GridViewImageAdapter;
import com.example.admin.helper.AppConstant;
import com.example.admin.helper.JSONfunctions;
import com.example.admin.helper.Utils;
import com.example.admin.ndimageslider.R;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class GridViewActivity extends Activity {

    private Utils utils;
    private ArrayList<String> imagePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
    private GridViewImageAdapter adapter;
    private GridView gridView;
    private int columnWidth;


    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
   // ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> imagePaths;
    static String RANK = "rank";
    static String COUNTRY = "country";
    static String POPULATION = "population";
    static String FLAG = "flag";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_grid_view);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

        utils = new Utils(this);

        // Initilizing Grid View
        InitilizeGridLayout();

        new DownloadJSON().execute();

    }

    private void InitilizeGridLayout() {
        Resources r = getResources();
        float padding = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                AppConstant.GRID_PADDING, r.getDisplayMetrics());

        columnWidth = (int) ((utils.getScreenWidth() -
                ((AppConstant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS + 1) * padding)) / AppConstant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS);

        gridView.setNumColumns(AppConstant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS);
        gridView.setColumnWidth(columnWidth);
        gridView.setStretchMode(GridView.NO_STRETCH);
        gridView.setPadding((int) padding, (int) padding, (int) padding,
                (int) padding);
        gridView.setHorizontalSpacing((int) padding);
        gridView.setVerticalSpacing((int) padding);
    }

    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(GridViewActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android JSON Parse Tutorial");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            imagePaths = new ArrayList<>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                    .getJSONfromURL("http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jsonActors");

            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("actors");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    imagePaths.add( jsonobject.getString("name"));
                    imagePaths.add(jsonobject.getString("country"));
                    imagePaths.add( jsonobject.getString("spouse"));
                    imagePaths.add(jsonobject.getString("image"));
                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    // imagePaths.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new GridViewImageAdapter(GridViewActivity.this, imagePaths,columnWidth);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

}
```

this is my Gridview Adapter...

```
    package com.example.admin.adapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.admin.loadingimagefromwebgridandswipe.FullScreenViewActivity;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GridViewImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
    private int imageWidth;

    public GridViewImageAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> filePaths,
                                int imageWidth) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.filePaths = filePaths;
        this.imageWidth = imageWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.filePaths.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.filePaths.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(activity);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }


        String designationUrl = filePaths.get(position);
//        Log.d("designationUrl",""+designationUrl);
//        URL url = null;
//        try {
//            url = new URL(designationUrl);
//        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
//        Bitmap bmp = null;
//        try {
//            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
//        } catch (IOException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }

        Picasso.with(activity)
                .load(designationUrl)
                .resize(imageWidth, imageWidth).into(imageView);


        // image view click listener
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnImageClickListener(position));
        //Toast.makeText(GridViewImageAdapter.this,"url: "+designationUrl,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return imageView;
    }

    class OnImageClickListener implements OnClickListener {

        int _postion;

        // constructor
        public OnImageClickListener(int position) {
            this._postion = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // on selecting grid view image
            // launch full screen activity
          //  Toast.makeText(GridViewImageAdapter.this,"url: "+,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(activity, FullScreenViewActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("position", _postion);
            activity.startActivity(i);
        }

    }

    /*
     * Resizing image size
     */
    public static Bitmap decodeFile(String filePath, int WIDTH, int HIGHT) {
        try {

            File f = new File(filePath);

            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            final int REQUIRED_WIDTH = WIDTH;
            final int REQUIRED_HIGHT = HIGHT;
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_WIDTH
                    && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_HIGHT)
                scale *= 2;

            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Fullscreen imageViewActivity....

```
    package com.example.admin.loadingimagefromwebgridandswipe;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.example.admin.Application;
import com.example.admin.adapter.FullScreenImageAdapter;
import com.example.admin.helper.JSONfunctions;
import com.example.admin.helper.Utils;
import com.example.admin.ndimageslider.R;

public class FullScreenViewActivity extends Activity{

    private Utils utils;
    private FullScreenImageAdapter adapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ImageView flag;
private  ImageView image;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_view);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        utils = new Utils(getApplicationContext());
        //flag=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.flag);
        image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        int position = i.getIntExtra("position", 0);
        adapter = new FullScreenImageAdapter(FullScreenViewActivity.this,
                Application.url());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // displaying selected image first
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        }
}
```

FullScreenImageAdapter:

```
 package com.example.admin.adapter;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.example.admin.helper.TouchImageView;
import com.example.admin.ndimageslider.R;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FullScreenImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<String> imagePaths;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    // constructor
    public FullScreenImageAdapter(Activity activity,
                                  ArrayList<String> imagePaths) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.imagePaths = imagePaths;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.imagePaths.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        TouchImageView imgDisplay;
        Button btnClose;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fullscreen_image, container,
                false);

        imgDisplay = (TouchImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
        btnClose = (Button) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnClose);

//        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
//        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
//        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_imagePaths.get(position), options);
//        imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        Picasso.with(activity)
                .load(imagePaths.get(position)).into(imgDisplay);

        // close button click event
        btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                activity.finish();
            }
        });

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(viewLayout,0);

        return viewLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

    }

}
```

Application:

```
    package com.example.admin;

import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.admin.helper.FileCache;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Application extends android.app.Application {

    public  static ArrayList<String> url(){
        ArrayList<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();

       filePaths.add("http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jsonActors");




        return filePaths;
    }
}
```

JSONfunctions:

```
package com.example.admin.helper;

/**
 * Created by Admin on 14-03-2016.
 */

import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class JSONfunctions {

    public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONObject jArray = null;

        // Download JSON data from URL
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // Convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {

            jArray = new JSONObject(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return jArray;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to implement Viewpage in your application. Take a look at this tutorial for the application you are trying to make.

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/

Follow this link. Cheers.

Comment: thanks for your responce...but i need JSON response (loading from web)for my image....that is the problem for me...